# Reusing Angular component

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-scope, components

I am creating  component based Angular app using Angular version 1.5.5 and typescript. In the header component I have country dropdown. That header component is re-used in multiple pages. Once the country is selected from the dropdown that particular scope lies only for that page, once I navigate to other page its got lost.

Is there any better way to reuse the component based on my scenario?

Comment: Save selection in local/sessionStorage/backend/cookie.

Comment: @dfsq keep selection in localstorage will lead to events to update the value.. that will affect the performance

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions,

1. You can make use of $rootScope since its globally available, keep the country in $rootScope so that once you changed the model it will be available in the other pages as well
2. I don't know whether its suits your situation, If you are using angular routing keep the header component outside ng-view so that it will not change will navigating through different pages.

Comment: As per project implementation criteria $rootscope is not allowed and that header is not through the application it limited only to few pages